# how to give to the user a feedback message after "save" function codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

normally I would return a JSON with a message about the status of my function, if error or success, but, this time, I'm with a trouble. I'm developing an application with PHP to register students to join the university, the database has a lot of tables to insert data about the student, things like, parents, student address, student course, course value and much more, so, after the user fill all the form fields and press submit, I do a lot of insert and updates, like 10 inserts in differents tables, my question is, how I can return a message of status after all this operation, if one of my inserts fail, how I can handle it to give to the user a feedback about this? I'm a little new to CodeIgniter, here one example of how I do my inserts in my save function at controller:

```
$studentData = array(
'FIELD1' => $data1,
'FIELD2' => $data2,
'FIELD3' => $data3
);
$this->mymodel->insert('STUDENTTABLE', $data);
```

I do so many inserts like this above. how can I return a feedback of every insert and at final of my save function to return a success message?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set flash data in your controller

$this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'This is my message');

// After that you need to used redirect function instead of load view such as 
redirect("admin/signup");


// Get Flash data on view  in view page
$this->session->flashdata('message_name');
```

For more reference, you can visit:[this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=set_flashdata#CI_Session::set_flashdata)

---

[tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_flashdata.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques to know that you inserted successfully or not.

1. You can use this `$this->db->affected_rows()` function to know after query it will return you affected row. you can simply use if condition to it to check.

   ```
   return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
   ```
2. `$this->db->insert_id();` this function will return you the last inserted id so depends on that you can do further coding.
3. The Best Way to find the query execution result is **Transactions**. I am not adding much description here because you can find it in the user guide of CodeIgniter. Here is the [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#transactions). I am just adding an example of it so you can get the little idea of it.

   ```
   $this->db->trans_begin();

   // Your query 

   if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
   {
           $this->db->trans_rollback();
   }
   else
   {
           $this->db->trans_commit();
   }
   ```

I personally prefer the transaction for `insert` and `update` query. It is very useful if you are adding multiple data or doing more than one activity regarding the database.

Now For Passing the Message to the View.

If you use the above technique and return true or false from model to controller then it would be easy to get message according to that.

I am adding sample model, controller and view code for you.

```
public function your_model_function(){

    // Do query
    // Return TRUE or FALSE

}

public function your_controller_function(){

    $data = $this->input->post(); // Your post data. You can use get also.
    $result = $this->your_model->your_model_function($data);

    //Normal Pass the variable to the view [OPTION-1]
    if($result == TRUE){
        $msg = "Successfully Insert.";
    }else {
        $msg = "Failed To Insert.";     
    }   

    $this->load->view('your_view',['msg'=>$msg]); // Change this code as per your requierment.

    //Now For Flash Data [OPTION-2]

     if($result == TRUE){
         $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Successfully Insert.');
    }else {
        this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Failed To Insert.');      
    }   

    //redirect to your page 
    return redirect('your_controller/your_controller_function'); // Change this code as per your requierment.

}
```

View For [Option-1]

```
<?php echo $msg; ?>
//OR
<?php print_r($msg); ?>
```

View For [Option-2]

```
<?php
    if ($feedback = $this->session->flashdata('feedback')){
        echo $feedback;
    }
?>
```